# compare multiple arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have 2D arrays (@AoA) that contains references to other arrays of strings. Size of this @AoA is different each time. I would like to compare each of these arrays of strings to each other.
To compare first array of strings to each other I can use something like this:

```
for (my $i=0; $i < $#AoA; $i++) {
    my $lcm = List::Compare->new( $aAoA[$i],  $AoA[$i+1] );
    my @intersection = $lcm->get_intersection;
    if (@intersection) {
      #some code here
    }
```

But what the best way to compare Each array with Each other?
I would like the results like this:

```
        Arr1    Arr2      ….          ArrN
Arr1    x      1 match  3 matches   0 matches
Arr2           x        N matches   3 matches
….                         x        1 match 
ArrN                                 x
```

Comment: If the lists are sorted you can probably do it much more efficiently. Are they?

Comment: @ neuhasus No, they are not sorted. Order of elements in each list contain certain info.

Comment: You could abuse Test::Deep.

Comment: @ simbabque The question is not about best method of comparison. I am fully satisfied with List::Compare intersection. The question is how to compare each element of @AoA with each other to get something like diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel comfortable with List::Compare, then you could use it instead of my function `intersect_count`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';
use List::Util 'any';

my @AoA = ([1,2,3,4,], [3,4,5,6], [4,7,8,9], [11,22,33]);

my @hdrs = map "Array_$_", 1 .. @AoA;
my $fmt = "%-10s" . "%-10s" x @hdrs . "\n";

printf $fmt, ' ', @hdrs;

for (my $i=0; $i < $#AoA; $i++) {
    my @matches;
    for (my $j = $i+1; $j < @AoA; $j++) {
        $matches[$j] = intersect_count( $AoA[$i], $AoA[$j]);
    }
    printf $fmt, $hdrs[$i], map $_ // ' ', @matches;
}

sub intersect_count {
    my ($a1, $a2) = @_;
    my $cnt;
    for my $item (uniq @$a1) {
        $cnt += any {$item eq $_} uniq @$a2;
    }
    return $cnt;
}
```

This prints

```
.         Array_1   Array_2   Array_3   Array_4
Array_1             2         1         0
Array_2                       1         0
Array_3                                 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps!